# Split an array into an equal chunks and keep big chunk last

Tags: php

I have an odd array of 7 elements contains some values :

```
$languages = ['php', 'mysql', 'java', 'nodejs', 'ruby', 'go', 'c#'];
```

I would like to split the array into equal chunks, and keep the big chunk last
for example I would like to have an output like:

```
[
  ['php', 'mysql'],
  ['java', 'nodejs'],
  ['ruby', 'go', 'c#']  // big chunk last as you can see
]
```

I tried to use `array_chunk` function :

```
return array_chunk($languages, 2);
```

but I got

```
 [
  ['php', 'mysql'],
  ['java', 'nodejs'],
  ['ruby', 'go'],
  ['c#']
]
```

Comment: You could still use array_chunk and somehow find a condition on which to merge the 2 last arrays ? :)

Comment: @IMCoins can you elaborate more please

Comment: If the 4th array of elements inside the "global" array is inferior to the size of the chunks you want (here, 2), you can make it so you apprend to the 3rd array the 4th array. Of course you would have to make this generic, but I'm sure you can handle given enough time ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the last chunk is undersized, and if so merge it into the previous.

```php
function special_chunk($array, $size) {
    $chunks = array_chunk($array, $size);
    $count = count($chunks);
    
    if( count($chunks[$count-1]) < $size ) {
        $chunks[$count-2] = array_merge($chunks[$count-2], $chunks[$count-1]);
        unset($chunks[$count-1]);
    }
    return $chunks;
}

$languages = ['php', 'mysql', 'java', 'nodejs', 'ruby', 'go', 'c#'];

var_dump(
    special_chunk($languages, 2)
);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "php"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "mysql"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "java"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "nodejs"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "ruby"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "go"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "c#"
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice :) If I may suggest one minor change though...
Change the if statement from "if( count($chunks[$count-1]) < $size )" to "if($count > 1 && count($chunks[$count-1]) < $size )"
Just in case the $chunks array only ends up with 1 element ;)

Answer (score 0):

To split the array into chunks and ensure that the last element is not less than the chunk size, make a modulus check and if it is not zero, merge the last two elements to become the final element.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Lffu5))

```
function chunkOverloadLast(array $array, int $size) {
    $result = array_chunk($array, $size);
    if (count($array) % $size) {
        $result[] = array_merge(...array_splice($result, -2));
    }
    return $result;
}

$languages = ['php', 'mysql', 'java', 'nodejs', 'ruby', 'go', 'c#'];

echo json_encode(chunkOverloadLast($languages, 2));
```