# Split an array into balanced chunks of a nominated minimum size with smaller chunks in the front and larger in the back

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, split, grouping

After reading [Split an array into an equal chunks and keep big chunk last](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74159279/2943403) and it's insufficiently challenging minimal verifiable example, I noticed in the lone, accepted answer that it was not robust enough to distribute excess elements to more than the last set so that the chunks of ascending minimal size were made balanced as much as possible.

For example, if the input array contained 8 elements and the minimum chunk size was `3`, the posted answer [will create imbalanced subarrays](https://3v4l.org/p776r) with sizes of 2, 2, and 4 instead of 4 and 4. And given a chunk size of `3` and an 11-element array, the answer [will create sizes of 2, 2, 2, 2, 3](https://3v4l.org/j19So) instead of 3, 4, 4.

I would like a function which:

- works like `array_chunk()`, but
- enforces a specified minimum number of elements per chunk and
- will endeavor to create balanced array sizes and
- will ensure that earlier populated chunks never have a greater size than a later populated chunk.

Fringe case handling: If the minimum chunk size is less than 1 or is greater than the count of the input array, throw an exception.

Test inputs and json encoded results (for brevity):

1. `$minChunk = 3; $array = range(1, 8);`

   ```
   [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
   ```
2. `$minChunk = 4; $array = range(1, 11);`

   ```
   [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10,11]]
   ```
3. `$minChunk = 2; $array = range(1, 5);`

   ```
   [[1,2],[3,4,5]]
   ```
4. `$minChunk = 3; $array = range(1, 9);`

   ```
   [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
   ```
5. `$minChunk = 7; $array = range(1, 13);`

   ```
   [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]]
   ```
6. `$minChunk = 1; $array = range(1, 4);`

   ```
   [[1],[2],[3],[4]]
   ```

Comment: Having looked at the original question, and trying the answer which you say would create a 2,2,4 split with 8 elements - it does what I would expect and splits them evenly 2, 2, 2, 2.  As all elements fit into the 2 size, why would you split them 2, 3, 3?

Comment: Right you are.  I've update the question to clarify.  Yes, a chunk size of 2 and an array of 8 elements should be split into 2, 2, 2, 2.  I was juggling too many scenarios in my head when I was posting the question and self-answer and I got tripped up in the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach which will calculate the appropriate subarray sizes and consume the input array from the back while looping to populate the result array.

Code: ([Demo with large battery of test cases](https://3v4l.org/BbcfI))

```
function littleEndianMinChunk(array $array, int $minChunkSize): array
{
    if ($minChunkSize < 1) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('$minChunkSize must be 1 or greater');
    }
    if (count($array) < $minChunkSize) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('$minChunkSize must not be less than the size of $array');
    }
    $result = [];
    while ($array) {
        $count = count($array);
        $modulus = $count % $minChunkSize;
        if (!$modulus) {
            array_unshift($result, ...array_chunk($array, $minChunkSize));
            break;
        }
        $expectedRemainingChunks = max(1, intdiv($count, $minChunkSize));
        $sizeIncrease = ceil($modulus / $expectedRemainingChunks);
        array_unshift($result, array_splice($array, -$minChunkSize - $sizeIncrease)); 
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: `if ($minChunkSize < count($array))`? I think that this is a typo

Comment: Correct.  Thank you, I've updated the answer and question.

Comment: Why does it matter if the size of the chunk required is larger than the input.  If I had [1,2] and wanted it in chunks of 10, then I would expect the output to be [[1,2]].

Comment: I suppose the goal was just to explicitly enforce the rule of minimum chunk sizes.  If someone was to post an answer that simply defaulted to a singled-chunked result array, I don't think I'd complain. @Nigel